# How can I tell IDEA to do clean test?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA and gradle.

When I invoke `Build | Build Project` command,

IntelliJ IDEA does this.

```
18:45:02: Executing tasks ':classes :testClasses'...

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
18:45:02: Tasks execution finished ':classes :testClasses'.
```

How can I tell IntelliJ IDEA do `:clean :test`?

I put, into `build.gralde`,

```
defaultTasks 'clean', 'test'
```

and it works when I do it in a console,

```
$ gradle -q
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `classes.dependsOn(clean)` (`classes` task depends on `clean` task) into your `build.gradle`. It should do the trick.

Before adding the line:

```
$ ./gradlew --dry-run :classes :testClasses
:compileJava SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:processTestResources SKIPPED
:testClasses SKIPPED
```

After adding the line:

```
$ ./gradlew --dry-run :classes :testClasses
:clean SKIPPED
:compileJava SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:processTestResources SKIPPED
:testClasses SKIPPED
```

**NOTE**, I performed the gradle test in the command line, it should work in the Intellij as well.